# microsoft shared point like web site

Tags: web-services, web-applications

My friend asked me if it is possible to build a web site like Microsoft shared point for his planning startup company. He want to share doc with his employees. I think the reason he asked is Microsoft is too expensive. I have no idea right now for this. Anybody knows anything about this? thanks,

EDIT:

Because docs shared are sensitive (contains SSN and other sensitive data), security should be good enough.

Comment: This is slide from Sun Java. If you are looking for choice on microsoft , sun has the Java application development. Take a look http://www.slideshare.net/uncled/microsoft-sharepoint-and-java-application-development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If he just wants to share file he could try Box.net or dropbox. Box.net also have simple workflows with tasks.

Comment: +1 for Dropbox. We had a similar requirement, and the cheapest, most secure and most user friendly solution was dropbox for sharing, and a CMS for the rest of the website.

Comment: +100 for Box, since they encrypt your data, and give you fine-grained controls over who has access to the documents

Answer (score 2):

I use Google Docs quite often and it is very useful. You can also setup a wiki and attach docs as needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft SharePoint Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en) is free and comes with a host of [features](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Tell your friend to sign up for [Microsoft BizSpark](http://www.bizspark.com/Pages/home.aspx).  This is a free program from Microsoft specifically for startups and will give them access to a whole [suite of software](http://www.bizspark.com/Programs/Pages/BizSpark_Software_and_Tools.aspx) for free for 3 years (with a $100 charge at the end).  This includes SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a combination of [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) and [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/). It's free, it's easy, and it eliminates the need to maintain the hardware and other infrastructure associated with a site, much less something as heavy-weight as Sharepoint.